# Why am I receiving error using ggadjustedcurves for a two group, adjusted survival model: Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survminer

I am attempting to plot adjusted survival curves for two groups (DEP+ vs DEP-), with this grouping information in the DEP_CAT variable column of the dataframe (SA.HYP.W). When trying to plot the survival of the DEP_CAT variable from the adjusted model, I receive this error:

```
Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

My cox proportional hazards model looks like this:

```
CPH.DEPMOD = coxph(Surv(TIME,STATUS) ~ DEP_CAT + AGE + GENDER + BMI + ALICE, data = SA.HYP.W)
```

I'm able to derive stats successfully, and then I try to plot the adjusted survival curves with ggadjustedcurves using the following code:

```
ggadjustedcurves(CPH.DEPMOD, data = SA.HYP.W, method = 'average', variable = 'DEP_CAT')
```

Seems to be pretty straightforward based on the online documentation, but then I receive the following error:

```
Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

I was expecting a plot of two different survival curves, one for DEP+ and DEP- based on the adjusted model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is, but I would like to point out that if you use `method="average"`, you are not actually adjusting for anything (i am not sure why this method even exists, but my questions fell on deaf ears when contacting the maintainer of `survminer`).

Maybe you could try using `method="conditional"` (which is the only method in the `ggadjustedcurves` function that actually estimates what you usually want to estimate, or you could try the `adjustedCurves` package instead (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adjustedCurves/index.html).